# Maximum and Minimum Problem - What are the dimensions of the open box that meets the following specifications?

Tags: calculus, optimization

What are the dimensions of the open box that meets the following specifications?
a) has maximum volume 
b) the base is a rectangle twice as long $(l)$ as it is wide $(w)$ 
c) you have $2400$ square inches of material to use (no waste)

I think I have to find the derivative of $v=whl$ and set it to $0$ but other than that I am unsure of what to do.

Comment: Conditions b) and c) can be converted to equations that $w$, $h$, and $l$ must satisfy. Those should allow you to write $V$ as a function of just one of the variables (pick whichever one makes you life easier). Can you take it from there?

Comment: @Kate J.: When you write down an equation like: $v=whl$, please add, "where $l$ is the length of (the base of) the box, $w$ is the width of (the base of) the box, and $h$ is the height of the box," etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the width of the box is $a$. Then, its length is $2a$. Suppose the box is $h$ tall (all measures are in $inches$). Then it has $2a^2$ base, and $2 \times ha$ $2 \times 2ha$ sides, all in $inch^2$. Thus, total surface area is $2400 inch^2$ such as: $$2400=2a^2+2\left(ha+2ha \right)$$
Thus,  $3ha=1200-a^2$ and hence, $h=\frac{1200-a^2}{3a}$
Now, volume of the box is $V$, then $$V=(a)(2a)(h)=2a^2\left(\frac{1200-a^2}{3a}\right)=2a\left(\frac{1200-a^2}{3}\right)$$
Now, get the first derivative of $V$ with respect to $a$:
$$\frac{dV}{da}=2\left(\frac{1200-a^2}{3}\right)+2a\left(\frac{-2a}{3}\right)=2\left(\frac{1200}{3}-\frac{3a^2}{3}\right)=2\left(400-a^2\right)$$
For critical points:$\frac{dV}{da}=0$, thus, $400-a^2=0$  $\Rightarrow a=\pm20$

Now, get the second derivative of $V$ with respect to $a$:
$$\frac{d^2V}{da^2}=2\left(-a\right)=-2a$$
$\frac{d^2V}{da^2}\lt 0$ only when $a=+20$ and that is maximum. Thus, the maximum volume of the box,$V_{max}$:
$$V_{max}=2\times20\left(\frac{1200-20^2}{3}\right)=10666\frac{2}{3} inch^3$$

Answer (score 1):

> I think I have to find the derivative of $v=whl$ and set it to $0$ but
>   other than that I am unsure of what to do."

Close.  In order to do this, you need a function of one variable.  So, right now, your function is in three variables, $w$, $h$, and $l$.  You need more equations to reduce them.  Thankfully, there is information in your problem that can add additional equations to reduce the number of variables!

1) "$2400$ square inches of material to use" - that's your surface area.  Do you know of the equation for the surface area of a box?

2) "the base is a rectangle twice as long as it is wide" - that is an equation that relates two of your sides.

You can use #$1$ and #$2$ to reduce the problem down to where $v$ is in terms of a single variable.  *Then* take the derivative and set it to zero.  The location where this is found is the value that *has* the maximum.

Then, go back and use #$1$ and #$2$ again to solve for the other dimensions.

Technically, you should also check the second derivative to make sure that this is a maxima and not a minima, and check the graph to make sure that there aren't any other maxima and minima you are missing.  But, given the problem, I'm sure your answer will be the maximum.